# How can I declare hashmap?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, hashmap, declare

I want to check this function's result.
  but cannot fix declare error!

```
    import java.util.HashMap;


    public class twosum {
        public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
```

> ```
>    Map<Int, Int> map = new HashMap<>();
> ```
>
> *java: generics are not supported in -source 1.3 
>           java : diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.3*

```
            for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
                map.put(nums[i],i);
            }
            for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
                int complement = target - nums[i];
                if(map.containsKey(complement) && map.get(complement) != i){
                    return new int[] { i, map.get(complement)};
                }
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution");
        }
        public void main(String[] args){

            int nums[] = {1,2,3,4};
            System.out.println(twoSum(nums,5));

            for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                System.out.println(i+"->"+"map="+map);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Set the project Java level to 1.8.

Comment: This looks like your IDE is set to build in Java 1.3 mode.  This is _very_ old, and you should change it, ideally to Java 8.  Which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

or

```
   Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

Comment: That doesn't help fix the described error of *"java: generics are not supported in -source 1.3 java : diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.3"*. Sure, once that error is corrected, the next error will be fixed by what you're suggesting, but you're not answering the actual *question*. I won't down-vote, because your answer is *slightly* helpful, but it's not exactly *useful* either, so no up-vote.